# Dynamic columns using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table that looks like this:

Main table

| id | bomname | styleid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bom1 | 101 |
| 2 | bom2 | 102 |
| 3 | bom3 | 103 |

this is detail table

| Id | bomId | bomKey | bomValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | part | cllr |
| 2 | 1 | unit | kg |
| 3 | 1 | qty | 123 |
| 4 | 1 | part | body |
| 5 | 1 | unit | kg |
| 6 | 1 | qty | 456 |
| 7 | 2 | part | slm |
| 8 | 2 | unit | kg |
| 9 | 2 | qty | 789 |
| 10 | 3 | part | abc |
| 11 | 3 | unit | kg |
| 12 | 3 | qty | 789 |
| 13 | 3 | color | red |

I hope query styleid=101  show this data list using `PIVOT`:

| part | unit | qty | ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cllr | kg | 123 | [1,2,3] |
| body | kg | 456 | [4,5,6] |

I hope query styleid=103  show this data list using `PIVOT`:

| part | unit | qty | color | ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | kg | 789 | red | [10,11,12,13] |

This is my SQL code:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '', @col_list nvarchar(max) = ''

SET @col_list = (SELECT DISTINCT QUOTENAME(bomKey) + ','  
                 FROM BomDetail 
                 FOR XML PATH(''))

SET @col_list = LEFT(@col_list, LEN(@col_list) - 1)

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @col_list + 
           ' FROM
                 (SELECT bomKey, bomValue FROM BomDetail) x
             PIVOT
                 (MAX([bomValue]) FOR [bomKey] IN (' + @col_list + ')
            ) AS p'

EXEC(@sql)
```

but now query returns only one row of data, how to modify my SQL code?

| part | unit | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| body | kg | 456 |

Comment: add a `print @sql` before your exec and post your result

Comment: for `styleid=103`, `qty` should be `789` right ?

Comment: @Squirrel yes I have fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this!

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '', @col_list nvarchar(max) = ''

SET @col_list = (SELECT DISTINCT QUOTENAME(a.bomKey) + ','  
                 FROM DetailTable a join MainTable b on (a.bomId = b.id)
                 where b.styleid=101 --> CHANGE IT
                 FOR XML PATH(''))

SET @col_list = LEFT(@col_list, LEN(@col_list) - 1)

If Object_id('Tempdb..#Details') is not null
    Drop Table #Details

Create Table #Details (Seq Int, bomId Int,bomkey varchar(20), bomvalue varchar(20),id Int)

Insert #Details
select Row_Number() Over(Partition by d.bomkey Order by d.bomkey) Seq, d.bomId,d.bomkey, d.bomvalue,d.id 
from DetailTable d join MainTable m
on (d.bomId = m.id)
where styleid=101   --> CHANGE IT
Order by 1


SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @col_list + 
           ',Ids FROM
                 (select bomkey, bomvalue, ''['' + stuff((select '','' + cast(id as varchar(100))  from #Details b where b.seq = a.seq for xml path('''')),1,1,'''') + '']'' Ids from #Details a ) x
             PIVOT
                 (MAX([bomvalue]) FOR [bomKey] IN ('+@col_list+')
            ) AS p'

EXEC(@sql)
```

**Note:**

1. Replace the **StyleId** in TWO Places in this code
2. Replace with **MainTable** and **DetailTable** accordingly

Comment: thank you, your solution completely solved my problem ,thank you very much!